# ls /sys/class/udc > UDC "ls:write error: Device or resource busy"

Tags: linux, usb, ls, usb-otg

```
ls /sys/class/udc > UDC 
"ls:write error: Device or resource busy"
```

Trying to use my device as an OTG client, but I can't write to the UDC file. lsof returns nothing. Any suggestions would be highly appreciated.

The full script is as follows:

```
cd /sys/kernel/config/usb_gadget/ 
mkdir -p midi_over_usb 
cd midi_over_usb 
echo 0x1d6b > idVendor # Linux Foundation 
echo 0x0104 > idProduct # Multifunction Composite Gadget 
echo 0x0100 > bcdDevice # v1.0.0 
echo 0x0200 > bcdUSB # USB2 
mkdir -p strings/0x409 
echo "fedcba9876543210" > strings/0x409/serialnumber 
echo "Test" > strings/0x409/manufacturer 
echo "My Gadget" > strings/0x409/product 
ls /sys/class/udc > UDC
```

Comment: I see you have a midi device, check out aseqdump